# Any way write CSS for parent DIV given known children DIV ID?

Tags: html, css, dom, css-selectors

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Given I have no way to change the HTML file, only CSS file.

How can I add some CSS to the parent DIV if I only know the direct child DIV ID?

For example:

```
<div>
  <div id="child">
    content
  </div>
</div>
```

Anything like:  `#child:parent div` CSS rules?

Comment: would you like to go for jquery support?

Answer (score 1):

No, css selectors does not support it. In css4 there is something for it (but it is not available now):

```
$div > #child {
  /* here code for parent div */
}
```

Comment: The `$` syntax has already been abandoned. They will be replacing it with something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this but it using jquery

```
$('#child').parent().css({'background-color':'green','color':'black'});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/krish/yWAUD/)

Comment: Adding Javascript usually requires modifying the HTML file, which he said he can'tdo.